# Foreign Key Constraint error when trying to update database, working with C# and ASP.NET Core, Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is the error I'm getting:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Battlestation_AspNetUsers_UserId' on table 'Battlestation' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is the model that contains the property with the foreign key:

```
    public class Setup{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId {  get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string SetupName { get; set; }

    public string SetupDesc { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile SetupImgFile { get; set; }

    public string ImgPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsFavourited { get; set; }

    // Navigation property for users who have favorited this setup
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser? FavouritedByUser { get; set; }

    public Setup()
    {
        
    }
}
```

}

ApplicationUser:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BattlestationHub.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display name is required.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Display name cannot exceed 50 characters.")]
        [UniqueDisplayName]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        // Navigation property for setups that the user has favorited
        public ICollection<Setup> Favourites { get; set; } = new List<Setup>();

    }
}
```

Comment: You should also post the ApplicationUser's model build-up, then we could know what happened.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Edited post to include ApplicationUser

Comment: Did your identity user contains the  UserId  property?

Comment: you can use this code in OnModelCreating to skip the error  modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser >().HasNoKey();

Answer (score 0):

Since the `DbContext` class was not provided, I just assume that the problem is that in the `DbContext.OnModelCreating()` method you need to specify what should the change tracker do if you call a delete or update operation on an entity that has foreign key constraints.

See [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete) on cascading operations. Basically, you need to do something like this (depending on what you want to do with associated entities on delete):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
    .Entity<Blog>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Owner)
    .WithOne(e => e.OwnedBlog)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

}